# How do I delete duplicity rows without PK? (normal select, disctint select)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Here's the situation

```
select name,surname,address from myTable -- returns 150rows

select distinct name, surname, address from myTable -- returns 60rows
```

Let's say, that I can't operate with PK. How do I delete duplicate rows?

```
select name,surname,address from myTable
MINUS
select distinct name, surname,address from myTable
```

is not working... MINUS delete everything

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Repeat after me: "On my honor as a database developer and user I swear/affirm/promise that I will always, Always, ALWAYS define a primary key on every table I create - even when I'm being too effing smart for my own good and just *know* that this time I don't really need one - so help me Codd".

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
delete FROM 
   myTable A
WHERE 
  a.rowid > 
   ANY (
     SELECT 
        B.rowid
     FROM 
        myTable B
     WHERE 
        A.name = B.name AND
        A.surname=B.surname AND
        A.address=B.address
        );
```

Note: I haven't tested this.

Comment: Testing **DELETE**-Queries is highly overrated! ;)

Comment: Yeah... :) Exactly! But I made this query from a working example.

Answer (score 0):

How about a new table?

```
create myTable2 as (select distinct name, surname, address from myTable);
drop myTable;
```